# Flex viewstack children includeIn works funny

Tags: apache-flex, states, viewstack

I have a viewstack with childrens which I want to show/hide depending on the state the application is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:eworx="com.eworx.*"
               xmlns:view="com.eworx.view.*" 
               xmlns:components="com.eworx.view.components.*"
               skinClass="com.eworx.view.skins.MainAppSkin" 
               xmlns:layouts="com.eworx.view.layouts.*"
               currentState="login"
               initialize="init(event)"
               creationComplete="complete(event)" 
               width="100%" 
               height="100%">


    <fx:Style source="assets/css/screen.css" />
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import nl.demonsters.debugger.MonsterDebugger;

            private var debugger:MonsterDebugger;

            [Bindable]
            public var apiUrl:String;

            [Bindable]
            public var customerType:String;



            protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                debugger = new MonsterDebugger(this);
            }

            protected function complete(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var activated:Boolean = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.activated;
                var passwordReset:Boolean = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.passwordReset;
                var message:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.message;

                apiUrl = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.apiUrl;

                if(activated)
                {
                    Alert.show(message,"Notice");
                }

                if(passwordReset)
                {
                    Alert.show(message,"Notice");
                }

                systemManager.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL,onMouseWheel,true);

            }

            private function onMouseWheel(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                e.delta *= 5;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <eworx:Seven7Context contextView="{this}" />
        <s:Fade id="fadeIn" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="300" />
        <s:Fade id="fadeOut" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="300" />
        <s:Rotate3D id="r3d" angleYFrom="0" angleYTo="360"  duration="300" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="login" />
        <s:State name="wholesale"  />
        <s:State name="retail"  />
    </s:states>

    <view:LoginForm id="loginForm" includeIn="login" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />

    <s:Group excludeFrom="login" width="960" horizontalCenter="0">

        <s:BitmapImage width="100%" height="42" x="13" y="80" source="@Embed('assets/garnish/bar.png')" />
        <mx:Image source="assets/garnish/logo.png" top="23" />

        <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" x="198" y="47">
            <s:TabBar  skinClass="MainMenuTabBarSkin" dataProvider="{vs}"  buttonMode="true"/>
            <mx:LinkButton id="logout" label="Logout" click="{currentState='login'}" />
        </s:HGroup>

        <s:HGroup top="0" right="0" gap="1" verticalAlign="top">
            <components:OfferList />
            <components:MarginBuildersTrack />
            <components:CartTrack top="0" />
        </s:HGroup>

        <mx:ViewStack 
            id="vs" 
            top="120"
            horizontalCenter="0" 
            width="960" 
            height="100%" 
            resizeToContent="true" >
            <view:HomePage showEffect="{fadeIn}" hideEffect="{fadeOut}" label="Home" />
            <view:ShowroomPage showEffect="{fadeIn}" hideEffect="{fadeOut}" label="Showroom" />
            <view:CataloguePage showEffect="{fadeIn}" hideEffect="{fadeOut}" label="Catalogue" />
            <!--<view:IncentivesPage showEffect="{fadeIn}" hideEffect="{fadeOut}" label="Incentives" />-->
            <view:RetailCustomerProfilePage includeIn="retail" showEffect="{fadeIn}" hideEffect="{fadeOut}" label="My Profile" />
            <view:WholesaleCustomerProfilePage includeIn="wholesale" showEffect="{fadeIn}" hideEffect="{fadeOut}" label="My Profile" />
            <view:ClientsPage excludeFrom="retail,login" showEffect="{fadeIn}" hideEffect="{fadeOut}" label="My Clients" />
            <view:CartPage showEffect="{fadeIn}" hideEffect="{fadeOut}" label="My Cart" />
            <view:OrdersPage showEffect="{fadeIn}" hideEffect="{fadeOut}" label="My Orders" />
        </mx:ViewStack>
    </s:Group>

</s:Application>
```

AS you can see I inlude the retail customer view in the retail state and the wholesale customer view in the wholesale state. The problem is that when I run my app they don't appear on neither state.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd approach to me.  The whole purpose of the ViewStack is to only show one item at once.  This is a very odd approach.

I see you have a tabbar whose dataProvider is the ViewStack.  However, your ViewStack is not created as a bindable property on the component, and you never seem to set up an initial state.  So, I theorize that this is happening:

1. App Loads in default state, which is the empty string
2. ViewSTack and/or TabBar are initialized without those children
3. App state changes for some reason
4. TabBar does not update

CreationPolicy may come into play too, but I'm not sure.  You'll have to step through the code to figure out what's going on.  I would strongly recommend you consider an alternate approach to this.  Possibly creating the tabbar navigator dataProvider manually based on user security settings or the current state.

Comment: My App has a default state of "login" which has a login form view. When a user logins I check if he is a retail or wholesale customer and accordingly change the currentState. So I want to have different views for each type of user. I use the viewstack for the application views and tabbar for the navigation. Why is it an odd approach. By the way changing the creationPolicy to all it works but I have the initial overhead.

Comment: I have never seen anyone use a ViewStack as the dataProvider of a TabBar.  I have never seen anyone use "includeIn" for children of a ViewStack.  It is those reasons I Say it is odd.  Most approches I've sen use either states or ViewStacks; but you're mixing the two.  That is why I say it is odd.  Since it works as you would have expected, when creationPolicy is set to all, I'll just point you to my original theory about ViewStack binding and the TabBar not changing.

Comment: In the "login" state, neither Retail or Wholesale exist b/c of your includein usage. When you change states, the TabBar's dataProvider doesn't update update because the ViewStack is not made to be Bindable.  I bet it'll work if you create the ViewStack in ActionScript and make it Bindable.  That will be a bit tedious, though b/c then you'll have to create all the ViewStack's children in AS3 too.

Comment: I've taken into consideration what you've said and I've made two arraycollections to use as a dataprovider for the tabbar depending on the state and I've removed includein from the viewstack. Creation pollicy:all added to much overhead.